# How to Get Rid of Bed Hair Without a Shower

Tags: personal-care, hair

I have pretty early starts in the mornings and as a result sometimes do not leave myself enough time to have a shower before needing to leave for work, usually as a result of a healthy use of the snooze button.
I have the unfortunate burden of having hair that really doesn't fair too well in the night, making it pretty messy and it is obvious that I have not showered. As a result I get referred to as delightful things such as 'Stinky McGee' or 'Homeless Henry'. This is somewhat undesirable and has forced me to try to conquer the issue of bed hair in the morning. Things I have tried:

- ***Combing my hair*** - I look like a little 'Gay Boy' and that's another quote from my work buddies. Plus it doesn't really do anything to the stubborn tufts
- ***Throwing water on it and drying*** - As I get lots of tufts sticking up, I do this in an attempt to flatten them all down again. Alas, it doesn't work and makes my hair smell. Nickname: 'Wet Dog Donald'
- ***Washing the night before*** - Although it feels soft and fluffy, still sticks up and looks like I've had a raucous night in the bedroom. Nickname: 'Sweaty Lover'
- ***Hair Gel / Wax*** - More often than not I end up looking like, and I quote, 'Grease Ball Gavin'.

As I have had little succes and a lot of abuse from my attempts, I hope you fine folks could 'help a brother out'.

---

***Notes:*** My hair is pretty thick and medium in length - I get it cut quite short when I go to the barbers but still have issues.

***Disclaimer:*** I do not genuinely get abused, it's just more fun this way.

Comment: Maybe combing your hair with a wet comb? I don't have your hair type, but this often works for me... also, avoid the comb lines by messing it up a little afterwards :)

Comment: The best advice I can give is to go to bed early enough that you don't need a snooze button. Kill the problem at its roots.

Comment: +1 This isn't an issue for everyone; but some hair types don't recover easily from bed hair.

Comment: @MrPhooky, McGee meaning?

Answer (score 5):

I have had a similar problem; when there is no time for a morning shower, I do a "simulated shower", which consists of:

1. Thoroughly wet the hair all the way through (kitchen sink?)
2. Dry the hair thoroughly with a towel
3. Comb it like you normally would after a shower.

Some hair types can stop there; mine will stand up as it becomes completely dry, so I add another step:

4. Wear a hat for about 5 minutes.

This way, you'll be "stylin' sammy"

Comment: I do the same, just bend over the sink and run water through my hair, dry it, comb it, it the door.

Answer (score 3):

First of all I need to say I really laughed with your question and specifically with the nicknames for every case..

To the point now. My hairdresser gave me this advice and it works. Put some lemon on your hair. Especially on those parts that are messy. Do not put too much lemon. I put a teaspoon in my hands and then try to fix my hair as I would if I used wax. Then (important!) get a hair dryer at full speed and heat and with it's help put your hair to the desired position. Don't have it too close or for too long. Just a few seconds for the lemon to dry and for the hair to take more shape. Too much time or too close will result in 'Elvis has left the building' type of nicknames.

This way your hair will stand as you want and also will not have a wet look. Just watch out not to put any lemon seeds on your hair or else your nickname will be 'head gardener' or something.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever this happens to me, I usually just wet my hair, throw in some shampoo and wash it really quickly. Afterwards I use a towel to dry some of it and leave the home with semi-wet hair and let it dry in the outside air as I walk to work.

Works better than anything else that you mentioned, also you get clean hair in a 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Bed hair in the morning is horrible but this works for me, I put my head upside down and blow dry my hair and brush it starting on hot blow dry then to finish I dry it on cool. Then I flip my head back up shape as normal and a bit of hairspray to keep the frizz down

Answer (score 1):

I too have excellent bed head lol. As a stylist, I would recommend styling your hair with a dime of wax. Emulsifying through hands and fingers on wet hair (no more than a dime!) then I would take the dryer on high and literally push the hair with your fingers and hands to the style that best suits your “normal look” and after it’s completely dried, go to bed! You may have some cow licks in the morning but a simple water and blow dryer touch up will do the trick in seconds! 
Or hey! Try the lemon thing... I hadn’t heard of that one.

Answer (score 0):

Just shave your head, your life will be better if you do it, trust me. My life is much easier because I shaved my head.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get all of your hair wet (you can use the bathroom sink)
2. Comb your hair
3. Dry your hair with a towel
4. Comb your hair again

Answer (score 0):

I suffer from bed-head to, and the best solution I can offer is to run it through with a wet comb, so it gets "damp" but not wet, then let it air dry.

@axsvl77 had a good solution as well, though I have not tried it.

My last few solutions are less concerned with your hair and center more around your environment. (All my suggestions below were/are endorsed by a healthy trip to google and/or what worked for me personally)

---

Do you live in a hot, muggy, place? If you do, when I lived in Connecticut during the summer I would always have this issue. Investing in a dehumidifier worked well enough.

While I don't share your hair type, using an anti-frizz shampoo seemed to get it under control. A good recommendation for this is "Suave Ultra Sleek and Smooth Frizz Control For Men."  Even though I don't have frizzy hair, anti-frizzy shampoo really worked. (Note: I didn't use that particular one, being female, but a quick look at the review tab showed good reviews.)

And lastly, silk and satin pillow cases might help!

Hope your hair troubles work out :)